# Access to local temporary tables not working anymore

Tags: sql-server, tls1.2

We have a very old program written in VB6 that was working fine. Now we found a bug where something that was working well a few month ago is not working anymore. Luckily I had an older virtual machine with the working code and a newer virtual machine with the buggy code to compare and debug.

After a lot of searching and trying I figured out the code change that is causing the bug, but I don't know what to do against it, since this code change is necessary and can't be taken back (at least not that I know of).

Maybe you can help?

Here's the description of what isn't working and why it isn't working.

---

This VB6 program connects to a SQL database (Microsoft SQL-Server 2017, but the version of the SQL-Server shouldn't be relevant). Then it's supposed to create a report.

For that the code creates a temporary local table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #tTempTable ...
```

This temporary table is filled with data and then queried to create the report.
For all this a connection string like this was used:

```
Data Provider=SQLOLEDB;Provider=MSDatashape;Integrated Security=SSPI;...
```

A few weeks ago this connection string was changed to (the data provider changed):

```
Data Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Provider=MSDatashape;Integrated Security=SSPI;...
```

This change causes the VB6 program to stop working. The temporary local table can still be created and filled with data, but the querying fails and tells that there's no object "#tTempTable".

If I switch back to the old data provider it works again.

If the check-in comment is right, this change of the data provider was done because the old one doesn't work with TLS 1.2 (this is not my field of expertise, so I don't know anything about that).

Right now I don't know how to fix that, except for maybe switch from temporary tables to persistant ones, or is there anything else I can do?, Maybe using another data provider that is working with TLS 1.2 and with temporary tables?

Comment: *"This change causes the VB6 program to stop working."* That doesn't tell us anything. What's the error, or the unexpected behaviour? What does "stop workign" mean, and what messages go with it?

Comment: Read one sentence ahead: _The temporary local table can still be created and filled with data, but the querying fails and tells that there's no object "#tTempTable"._

Comment: Guessing your statements are being run in different connections, so `#tTempTable` doesn't exist. Without code, impossible to be certain, but that it my guess.

Comment: But the creation and the filling of the temp table still works, just the querying fails.

Comment: Which, I can only guess, is done using a new connection.

Comment: The code between "working" and "not working" is exactly the same, except for the differing data provider. So, if using different connections would be the problem, then Microsoft would be switching connections inside their new data provider and the question would be, how to avoid that?

Comment: But I can't see that code, so I can only guess, like I've said. You have code that isn't working, but haven't supplied said code; so this is impossible for us to do more than guess at.

Comment: _"...the check-in comment..."_ You have a development problem that you apparently cannot solve. Kick it back to the developer who made the change or  escalate the issue to management. This sounds like a design problem from the start that was not exposed due to luck using the older interface. Someone needs to redesign this part of the code to use a single connection for the entire process.

Comment: I dont understand why the entire SQL String that builds the temp table and querying it wasnt sent as a single string.

Answer (score 0):

We have got the same problem after upgrading the SQL provider to a newer one that is compatible with TLS 1.2 due to a security requirement. The SQL Providers are the same mentioned above.

The only solution we've found was to rewrite the code to store the data in a permanent table and then issue a separate command to retrieve the results.

We've have seen this issue reported. It looks like a bug with ADO method and upgraded SQL Provider.